# Why does my operation not change value? [Class]

Tags: python, class

I have a simple program:

```py
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance (self, other):
        x_diff = (self.x-other.x)**2
        y_diff = (self.y - other.y)**2
        return (x_diff+y_diff)**0.5
    def __str__(self):
        return "<" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ">"
    def __sub__(self,other):
        return Coordinate(self.x - other.x,self.y - other.y)


c = Coordinate (3,4)
o = Coordinate (1,1)
```

`c - o` gives me `<2,3>`.

Now if I change `__sub__()` to:

```
    def __sub__(self,other):
        return self.x - other.x
```

and run the program:

`c - o` still gives me `<2,3>` instead of `2`.

Comment: Did you remember to save your edits before you ran the program again?

Comment: for some reason if i reinitialize my variables, i get the correct output. im using Spyder IDE fyi. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me.

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance (self, other):
        x_diff = (self.x-other.x)**2
        y_diff = (self.y - other.y)**2
        return (x_diff+y_diff)**0.5
    def __str__(self):
        return "<" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ">"
    def __sub__(self,other):
        return self.x- other.x

c= Coordinate (3,4)
o = Coordinate (1,1)
c - o
```

Output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see it returns 2.You might be doing something wrong. look at the picture
[code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Yz7.png)